# Python 3 rmdir raises Windows errors without added (arbitrary) delays

Tags: python-3.x, delay, rmdir

This code works. I am using it in a unittest where ~100 files and folders are quickly created and destroyed.

If I take out the sleep() statements then I get a range of Windows errors such as Directory does not exist errors and Directory Permissions errors.

I am embarrassed by the inclusion of the sleep message - which seem like a rather ugly 'hack'. Obviously on my target systems I can't know that sleep(1) is the right value. What is the proper adult solution that does not depend upon an arbitrary one second delay (the final system will be heavily loaded at times)?

```
    def removeDirectoryBranch(myPath):
        # delete a directory path and the files/folders in that directory
        sleep(1) # give the OS time to sort itself out
        for root, dirs, files in walk(myPath, topdown=False):
            # safety check removed for for this question
            # limits the scope of the function
            for name in files:
                remove(join(root, name))
            for name in dirs:
                rmdir(join(root, name))
        rmdir(myPath)
```

*Python 3.3 running on Windows 7 (using Eclipse and PyDev)*

*The preceding code is in a 'teardown' method of a unittest class. All files are opened and closed properly (in a try/except/finish structure)*

*The problem occurs randomly though the unitttest runs the same way each time (most of the time it does not need the sleep).*

Comment: Considering the ``sleep()`` is the first instruction, the problem lies not in the code you have posted, but the one that gets executed before.

Comment: The preceding code is in a 'teardown' method of a unittest class. All files are opened and closed properly (in a try/except/finish structure).

Comment: Can you use [`shutil.rmtree`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to remove the entire directory tree? (instead of reimplementing it?